# Flutter some image assets are shown and some are "unable to load"

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, dart, mobile

I am currently trying to use some images in my Flutter app. However I can't get behind the behaviour of Flutter. I am using an Ink.image with an AssetImage inside. Now when I use AssetImage('assets/images/history.jpg) it works. This goes for "food" and "animals" aswell. "Nature" and "Music" doesn't work. I just don't understand why some images work and others not.

My pubspec.yaml is just:

flutter:
assets:
- assets/images/

My folder structure for my images is:
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSf4h.png)

```
InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        onTap: () {},
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Ink.image(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/music.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                gradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent], begin: Alignment.bottomCenter, end: Alignment.topCenter),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 20,
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 0),
                  child: Text(title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 20,
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 0),
                  child: Text(author, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall?.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I already tried doing flutter pub get or deleting and inserting the images again.

Comment: `image: AssetImage('assets/images/music.jpg'),` have to be :  `image: AssetImage('assets/images/music/music.jpg')`, as `music.jpg` is inside `music` folder which is inside `assets` folder

Comment: @SNAN have you add image path in pubspec.yaml and use AssetImage('assets/images/music/music.jpg')

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
image: AssetImage('assets/images/music.jpg'),
```

to

```
image: AssetImage('assets/images/music/music.jpg'),
```